# Crop an Image by passing the image file path in Android

Tags: android, image, crop

I have tried the below code. However, it always results the 160*160 dimension image.

```
try {   
    //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    //indicate image type and Uri
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pictureFile), "image/*");
    //set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 100);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 100);
    cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);

    //indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 500);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 500);
    //retrieve data on return
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_IMAGE);

} catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    //display an error message
    String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

}
```

I would like to crop an image by passing its path. 
I don't want to capture/pick from default camera app or gallery. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have solved this by create a new file before calling Intent and passing this file path to store the cropped image through intent. Here is the solution for this.

```
private Uri mCropImagedUri;
private final int CROP_IMAGE = 100;//unique request code number. Which is used to identify the request result in onActivityResult()
/**Crop the image
 * @return returns <tt>true</tt> if crop supports by the device,otherwise false*/
private boolean performCropImage(){
    try {
        if(mFinalImageUri!=null){
            //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            //indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(mFinalImageUri, "image/*");
            //set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            //indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
            //indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 500);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 500);
            //retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);

            File f = createNewFile("CROP_");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                VLLog.e("io", ex.getMessage());  
            }

            mCropImagedUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCropImagedUri);
            //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_IMAGE);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
        //display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

private File createNewFile(String prefix){
    if(prefix==null || "".equalsIgnoreCase(prefix)){
        prefix="IMG_";
    }
    File newDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mypics/");
    if(!newDirectory.exists()){
        if(newDirectory.mkdir()){
            VLLog.d(mContext.getClass().getName(), newDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+" directory created");
        }
    }
    File file = new File(newDirectory,(prefix+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg"));
    if(file.exists()){
        //this wont be executed
        file.delete();
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return file;
}
```

So here we should not bother about the data which comes in `onActivityResult()` method.

Here is the complete information about cropping image. I have used this to solve. 
http://www.androidworks.com/crop_large_photos_with_android

Comment: If this is your preferred solution, then please mark it as such and close the question

Comment: After days of struggling finally worked well, tnx. What a stupid bug! >:O

Comment: what is "mFinalImageUri" here refers to?

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't support a cropping intent built in. You should not assume it's available.

Instead you should use your own solution, or use a third party library, like this one:

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Read more about it here:

https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Answer (score -4):

In this way,you can scale the image:

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,50,50,true);
```

Comment: I have to crop the image based on user selection and I posted the answer.

Comment: @HarshParikh : There is actually also a SO badge for this purpose (http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher) and is encouraged behavior.

Comment: Why you have down voted me.therefore,i have written this line