# How to crop image with known path based on user selection

Tags: android, crop

in my app I capture a photo using intent MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE and I save image into  external storage that is private to my app. I also save the path to taken picture.
In next step I would like to crop 3 pictures from this photo but I cannot figure out how to do it. I found this article [Crop an Image by passing the image file path in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463102/crop-an-image-by-passing-the-image-file-path-in-android) but the answer uses com.android.camera.action.CROP, which is often not supported. I would like to crop it like this

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.xyz);
resizedbitmap1=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0,0,yourwidth, yourheight);
```

but I need to crop picture according to user selection. Can anyone help me with this? I am pretty stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using some third party library for cropping pictures. I recommend you to do the same. You will find plenty of them on github, choose according to your preferences.